# Cursor alignment off in tab menu in browsers, terminal, text editor and thunderbird in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, cursor

Having upgraded from Ununtu 13.10 to 14.04, the cursor alignment is off in applications such as Firefox and Chromium (when selecting tabs, address bar, but not in main window), thunderbird (when selecting mails, folders) and text editor (selecting tabs).  There was no issue on the same laptop when using 13.10.
I've tried:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

which has not solved the problem.
The issue comes and goes.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

The issue appears to be when the applications are in full screen mode only.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this too. Minimising and then maximising the window seems to solve the issue.